# OSX App, NSTextField only responds to Force Click

Tags: xcode, macos, nstextfield, 3dtouch

I am writing my first OS X app and I am running into a problem. I am placing a NSTextField inside of a NSTableViewCell. A single click in the text field does nothing. A force click will, however, activate the textfield to enter text.

Is this because it's embedded in a cell?

So far my code is very simple:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    NSScrollView * tableContainer = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    mainTableView = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1200, self.frame.size.height)];
    mainTableView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable;

   /// {creating columns here}

    [tableContainer addSubview:mainTableView];
    mainTableView.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
    mainTableView.rowHeight = 25;
    [mainTableView setDelegate:self];
    [mainTableView setDataSource:self];

    [tableContainer setDocumentView:mainTableView];

    [tableContainer setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
    [self addSubview:tableContainer];

    [mainTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableColumn.width, tableView.rowHeight)];
    NSTextField *tf = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
    tf.stringValue = @"!";
    tf.editable = YES;
    tf.delegate = self;
    [view addSubview:tf];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Side note: You don't have to create your layout in `- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect`.

Comment: First of all, where does this code belong? NSTableCellView or an NSViewController? I ask because you have drawRect, which is a NSView method, and tableView:viewForColumn, which is a controller method. The two should not be in the same class. Second, you should not be creating and adding views in drawRect. drawRect is for you to layout your subviews (ie. settings frames).